# Display data on SQL Server of each row from an xls file by using powershell

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell, xls

I'm new to PowerShell. Please help me on how to achieve the following: display data on SQL Server of each row from an xls file by using PowerShell.

```
read xls > powershell > sql server
```

Below is the code I've created so far but turns out only one row of data is displayed in database. How do I loop the output of each row?

```
$filepath = "C:\Source\AandPrates.xls"

#object to open excel workbook
$excel= New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filepath)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$startRow = 4

#create system.datatable
#read xls file line by line and display on powershell
$dt = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable"
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("Currency Name",
  [System.Type]::GetType("System.String"))
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("ISO Code",
  [System.Type]::GetType("System.String"))
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("Accounting Rates",
  [System.Type]::GetType("System.String"))
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("Base Currency",
  [System.Type]::GetType("System.String"))
Do {
    $ColValues1 = $worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow,1).Value()
    $ColValues2 = $worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow,2).Value()
    $ColValues3 = $worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow,3).Value()
    $ColValues4 = $worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow,4).Value()
    $startRow++
    $dt.Rows.Add($ColValues1,$ColValues2,$ColValues3,$ColValues4)
   }
   while ($worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow,1).Value() -ne $null)

$name = $ColValues1
$code = $ColValues2
$rates = $ColValues3
$currency = $ColValues4

$Excel.Quit()

#Connect to the SQL database
$Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$Conn.ConnectionString = "Server=5CG61730W6\SQLEXPRESS;Database=shamsuli;trusted_connection=true;"
$Conn.Open()
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Conn

#insert the output from powershell into sql server
$output | foreach {
 $Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (Name,Code,Rates,Currency) VALUES (@Name, @Code, @Rates, @Currency)"
 $Command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Name", $name)));
 $Command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Code", $code)));
 $Command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Rates", $rates)));
 $Command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Currency", $currency)));
 $Command.ExecuteNonQuery() | out-null
}

$Conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I already get the answer for my question. Thanks btw. :)

```
$filepath = "C:\Source\AandPrates.xls"

#object to open excel workbook
$excel= New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($filepath)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$startRow = 2

#create system.datatable
$dt = New-Object "System.Data.DataTable"
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("Currency Name",
  [System.Type]::GetType("System.String"))
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("ISO Code",
  [System.Type]::GetType("System.String"))
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("Accounting Rates",
  [System.Type]::GetType("System.String"))
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("Base Currency",
  [System.Type]::GetType("System.String"))

Do {
    $name = $ColValues1
    $code = $ColValues2
    $rates = $ColValues3
    $currency = $ColValues4
    $ColValues1 = $worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow,1).Value()
    $ColValues2 = $worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow,2).Value()
    $ColValues3 = $worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow,3).Value()
    $ColValues4 = $worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow,4).Value()
    $startRow++
    $dt.Rows.Add($ColValues1,$ColValues2,$ColValues3,$ColValues4)

    #Connect to the SQL database
    $Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $Conn.ConnectionString = "Server=5CG61730W6\SQLEXPRESS;Database=shamsuli;trusted_connection=true;"
    $Conn.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Command.Connection = $Conn


    foreach ($worksheet in $excel) {

    $Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable1000 (Name,Code,Rates,Currency) VALUES (@Name, @Code, @Rates, @Currency)"
    $Command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Name", $name)));
    $Command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Code", $code)));
    $Command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Rates", $rates)));
    $Command.Parameters.Add((New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@Currency", $currency)));
    $Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    $Conn.Close()

   }
   while ($worksheet.Cells.Item($startRow,1).Value() -ne $null)

$Excel.Quit()
```